# Gradle exec commandline does not report mysql syntax error

Tags: gradle, exec

Gradle exec commandline does not report mysql syntax error.

```
task runSQL(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'mysql -u root -p123456 db1 < /path/db1.sql'

}

gradle runSQL
```

The db1.sql has syntax error. But the build is successful without reporting any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because mysql is returning as exit code -1, but cmd is not forwarding that. You can get around this by calling mysql directly:

```
commandLine 'mysql', '-u', 'root', '-p123456', 'db1', '<', '/path/db1.sql'
```

But mysql might be only in your cmd path. Then you would need to write the absolute path to the mysql binary.

Comment: The mysql path can be different on different platforms and for different mysql versions. The Exec does not look for the command in PATH environment? thanks.

Comment: This depends on the OS. I don't know exactly how it works on Windows. But if PATH does not work, you could just add a custom system environment variable MYSQL_HOME and get it via standard Gradle mechanism: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html